# Accessing Sharepoint 2013 (Office 365) without approval,tokens,apps,etc?

Tags: 2013

Instead of using an app, is there a way to impersonate a user and interact with SharePoint directly?

Essentially, is it possible to create a desktop application that accesses SharePoint on behalf of a user without explicit permission from SharePoint admins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [ClientContext and Office 365](http://brossgroup.com/2013/08/clientcontext-office-365/) how to use [`SharePointOnlineCredentials`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.sharepointonlinecredentials.aspx)

Comment: Any idea what needs to be installed for Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime reference? I am able to add the reference in VS, but the using statement does not recognise it.

Comment: If you install [SharePoint Server 2013 Client Components SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35585) the `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll` and `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll` will be at `C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI`

Comment: Interesting..  I have the dll there as well, and I can add the reference as well. However, the using statement gives a build error(and, intellisense does not work for it either ). Looks more like a VS issue I guess

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can use a browser or any other app under any context you choose, provided you have the credentials:

From the command line:

```
runas /user:Domain\User "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"
```

You'll get challenged for the pasword before the app starts but from then on, you're running under a different user name and context from the desktop login account. You can substitute the browser path for any application such PowerShell or SharePoint Designer, which I normally need to do on production systems to have workflows and the like run under different security accounts, etc.

Comment: I'm planning to write the app, so was looking for help on how to pass the credentials to SharePoint in such a case